# JQuery Toggle which disables other links

Tags: jquery

Is there a way of disabling another link, the re-enabling them with the toggle function.

here is my script so far. I would like to disable 'military' when I've clicked on 'Entertainment', but then re enable the link when the toggle returns.

```
$("[href='#Entertainment']").click(function () {
$("#Entertainment").toggle("slow");

});


$("[href='#Military']").click(function () {
$("#Military").toggle("slow");

});
```

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: How will the "toggle return" ? By clicking out of the sourceElement or by clicking again them or else ?

Comment: I don't think you can disable a link... May be resetting the href should help... Also what do you meant by toggle returns ??

Comment: Hey Matt,I have a solution for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out...

Here is a working example [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/nY2et/)

Setting up your html like so, giving the links an ID

```
<a id='Elink' href='#Entertainment'>Entertainment</a>
<a id='Mlink' href='#Military'>Military</a>
<div id='Entertainment'>EntertainmentContent</div>
<div id='Military'>Military Content</div>
```

Then on the click, after the toggle happens, a callback function checks to see whether the corresponding divider is visible, if it is, the other link is disabled, if not visible, then the other link is enabled

```
$("#Elink").on('click', eclick);    
$("#Mlink").on('click', mclick);


function mclick() {

        $("#Military").toggle("slow", function() {
            if ($("#Military").is(':visible')) {
                $("#Elink").attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);').off('click');
            } else {
                $("#Elink").attr('href', '#Entertainment').on('click', eclick);
            }
        });
}

function eclick() {
        $("#Entertainment").toggle("slow", function() {
            if ($("#Entertainment").is(':visible')) {
                $("#Mlink").attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);').off('click');
            } else {
                $("#Mlink").attr('href', '#Military').on('click', mclick);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: OK, so thats a great start, however, do you think theres a way to simultaneously open military and close entertainment and visa versa?

Comment: @MattJameson Yes, but then would you need to disable to links?

Comment: @MattJameson Did you want to do that instead? If not, if you feel I answered your question, please consider marking the answer accepted w/ the checkmark in the upper-left. :)

Comment: @MattJameson Awesome!  If you decide to go the other route, check this out.. http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/nY2et/4/

Comment: Is the any chance you could explain the Jquery to me please?

Comment: @MattJameson Which script? The one in my answer or the fiddle in my comments?

Comment: @MattJameson Here is the fiddle with Comments to explain what is happening :) http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/nY2et/6/

Comment: @MattJameson Here is an alternate method with comments using .index() instead of unique ID's for the links  http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/nY2et/7/

Comment: That's excellent, I completely get it now. I like it how you can group together ID's and treat them as one, then split them apart after when required. Clever stuff, thanks